# How to disable the filter being applied to an image in a dissabled button in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-button

When I dissable a button with a image on it, the image gets a white filter over it. I want to disable that filter, while keeping the button dissabled.

```
import tkinter
import PIL
import PIL.ImageTk

root = tkinter.Tk ()

img = PIL.Image.new (mode = "RGB", size = (100, 100), color = (255, 0, 0))

tkImg = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage (img, master = root)
b = tkinter.Button (root, image = tkImg)
b.pack ()
b.config (state = "disabled")
root.mainloop ()
```

[image: disabled button]

Comment: Can you please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve]? I don't see this behavior when I try to reproduce it.

Comment: i have just added the code